# Need help with filling matrix images into CSS grid

Tags: matrix, forloop

I want to fill in shuffled images into a CSS grid as a project overview. The images come from a matrix and have 4 different formats. So I want to fill in a format A image into the fitting grid cell (callA1, cellA2 ...). With my code, I have the problem, that the loop iterates over all items and fills all the A-sized cells with the same image. I would like to have image1 in cellA1 and image2 in cellA2 and image3 in cellB1 and so on.

```
{% for allProjects in craft.entries.section(['projekteZitate']).all() %} 
   {% set shuffledProjects = shuffle(allProjects) %}


       {% for block in shuffledProjects.projekteMatrix %}
                    {% if block.type == 'A' %}
                         {% set image = block.A.one() %}
                             {% if image %}
                              <li class="cellA1"> <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}"  alt="{{ image.title }}" /> </li>
                              {% endif %}
                    {% endif %} 

                    {% if block.type == 'A' %}
                         {% set image = block.A.one() %}
                             {% if image %}
                              <li class="cellA2"> <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}"  alt="{{ image.title }}" /></li>
                              {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if block.type == 'B' %}
                         {% set image = block.A.one() %}
                             {% if image %}
                              <li class="cellB1"> <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}"  alt="{{ image.title }}" /></li>
                              {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You have `block.type A` twice. Is that on purpose? Also I would look int to the `switch` syntax. It's more elegant when iterating trough matrix blocks.

Comment: Yes, this part of the layout consists of two images of size A and one size B image. They are put in position by the css grid. I would like to have good control of the positions of the image since this is important to the layout of the site. That is why I would like the pick the images one by one and put them in position.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to determine if an image should go to the first `block.type == 'A'` if statement or the second one

you could write something like this:

```
{% switch block.type %}
    {% case 'A' %}
        {# images for both case a1 + a2. write the loop number into the class name #}
        <li class="cellA{{ loop.index }}"> {# your image #}</li>
    {% case 'B' %}
        {# images for case b #}
        <li class="cellA1"> {# your image #}</li>
{% endswitch %}
```

That's just one of lots of possibilities